# How do I make ORDER BY work when creating a procedure in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

**I'm trying to create a procedure that inserts the data of a new lecturer, then shows the last 3 lecturers added. This is what my table (lecturers) looks like:**

```
emp_id INT UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
first_name VARCHAR(20),
last_name VARCHAR(20),
faculty VARCHAR(3)
```

**And this is my attempt to create the procedure:**

```
DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE new_lect (IN emp_id INT, first_name VARCHAR(20), last_name VARCHAR(20), faculty VARCHAR(3))
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO lecturers (emp_id, first_name, last_name, faculty) VALUES (emp_id, first_name, last_name, faculty);
        SELECT * FROM lecturers
        ORDER BY emp_id DESC 
        LIMIT 3;
        END//
DELIMITER ;
```

**Then I call the procedure with this data for example:**

```
CALL new_lect(109,'Charlie','Smith','MAT');
```

**However, ORDER BY does not seem to be doing its job because I always receive employee 100, 101, 102 instead of 107, 108, 109.**

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: This reproduces the problem:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=86980c636cd0e184696adec03c666afe.  It seems like your code should work.

Comment: this should be reported as Bug(yet another one)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You wrote a good question (even if the answer is "you found a bug in quarter-century old software").  I hope we'll see more contributions from you in future.

Comment: @nbk I find the reason. This is not a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of a problem is found !

[MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual / Stored Objects / Restrictions on Stored Programs / Name Conflicts within Stored Routines](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html#stored-routine-name-conflicts)

> The same identifier might be used for a routine parameter, a local
> variable, and a table column. Also, the same local variable name can
> be used in nested blocks.
>
> In such cases, the identifier is ambiguous and the following
> precedence rules apply:
>
> - A local variable takes precedence over a routine parameter or table
>   column.
> - **A routine parameter takes precedence over a table column.**
> - A local variable in an inner block takes precedence over a local
>   variable in an outer block.
>
> The behavior that variables take precedence over table columns is
> nonstandard.

In procedure's code `ORDER BY emp_id` is treated as ordering by procedure parameter `IN emp_id INT` which is constant.

So the procedure code must be

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE new_lect (IN emp_id INT, first_name VARCHAR(20), last_name VARCHAR(20), faculty VARCHAR(3))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO lecturers (emp_id, first_name, last_name, faculty) VALUES (emp_id, first_name, last_name, faculty);
    SELECT * FROM lecturers
    ORDER BY lecturers.emp_id DESC -- !!!!!
    LIMIT 3;
END
```

Answer (score 2):

As a temporary (?) solution you may use prepared statement:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE new_lect (IN emp_id INT, first_name VARCHAR(20), last_name VARCHAR(20), faculty VARCHAR(3))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO lecturers (emp_id, first_name, last_name, faculty) 
    VALUES (emp_id, first_name, last_name, faculty);
PREPARE stmt FROM 'SELECT * FROM lecturers ORDER BY emp_id DESC LIMIT 3;';
EXECUTE stmt;
DROP PREPARE stmt;
END
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8e5355825e8accdcc896a67a2700f1c7) (honestly stolen from [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff)'s comment).